# Upload bulk images to Picture Library and add Keywords at the same time (bulk key wording)

Tags: file-upload, library, picture, bulk

I know you can drag and drop multiple images into the Picture library (SharePoint 2013), but is there a way to then say, I want all of these images to have 'x' keyword?

Background....

I'm trying to make a picture gallery with multiple view depending on a 'keyword', to display only images with a certain keyword.

I can get it working for single uploads, but not multiple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of the quick edit functionality available in List/Library.

1. Bulk upload the images in groups.
2. After uploading a specific group of images, use quick edit to update the keyword column (can auto fill the columns by simply dragging the value. same like excel).

[image]